# SSH Hidden Service + gateway (tor2web)

Tags: onion-services, ssh

i followed this (http://gk2.sk/running-ssh-on-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-hidden-service-with-tor/) instruction how to how to run an hidden ssh server. It works so far.

Now I am wondering if it would be possible to access my server from the open Internet with help of an (public) proxy.

Right now my ideas was:

Server <-> hidden sevice <-> Tor2Web.org (or other service) <-> client

However SSH is unable to resolve the address

> MacBook-Pro:~ user$ ssh user@2qe36xcwuakfflis.tor2web.org:80
>   ssh:Could not resolve hostname 2qe36xxxxxxxxlis.tor2web.org:80: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

My goal is that I can access my server form every when, sometime it is not possible to direct tor access.

Any suggestions are welcome

Comment: tor2web uses an http proxy, it won't carry ssh traffic.

Comment: as people said, tor2web is the web proxy, https, it means it can't be used for ssh. beside it, if your server use port 22 for ssh, you can't use 80 for ssh. for example, I wrote in my server, the port 10000 for ssh, if I try 80 or 443 or 22 to login to my server, it will not work. I use debian, ssh port is written in: /etc/ssh/sshd_config (when you decide what port you will use for ssh, it will not let you to chose the same port as your web server, if your web server use 80 and 443, you must chose another one for ssh, all busy ports you can see with the command: netstat -tpln).

Comment: Using port 80 or 443 for SSH won't work if the proxy is only carrying HTTP traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Tor2Web is a web-page mirror thing, it's **defenately not a full-featured gateway** between a Darknet and a Clearnet/Internet. You must use dot-onion address in order to address your hidden service - that's how *any darknet* works, not just Tor.

The true meaning of darknet is to be... dark! In other words - not directly exposed to all the public in Clearnet. If you're using a darknet as a transport - *use it explicitly*.